# GMSL Deserializer to LCD Link Rate

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, display, tft, deserialiser

I need to calculate the Link Rate for my GMSL Deserializer which is connected to a 800 * 480 TFT Display.

In that case, I stumbled upon this [Article](https://maximsupport.microsoftcrmportals.com/en-us/knowledgebase/article/000100988)

On the last few lines, they are asking to multiply by 30 for RGB666 and 40 for RGB888.

I am not able to understand this. Why 30 for RGB 666 when 6+6+6 = 18. and same for RGB888.
Even if we including the HSYNC, VSYNC, EN bits, we will not get to 30 in RGB666 format and same for RGB88.

Can someone explain

Comment: Did you read pages 29 and 30 of your MAX9278 deserializer IC? The link contains also other data than video, and there is a line coding from 8-bit bytes to symbols larger than 8 bits. The actual link rate depends on which link mode you have selected to use. But I already told this when you previously asked the same thing; is this a duplicate question?

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the number of bits per pixel for each colour.  6 or 8

Comment: Yes, I understand like RGB666. So, 3 colours with 6 bits each. In that case, it would only be 6 + 6 + 6 = 18 right? Or 8 + 8 + 8 = 24 right?